# How to run the iphone app in xcode4 with breakpoints?

Tags: iphone

Iam doing one applciation.In that i put the some breakpoints.But they are not fired,directly program will be executed.Iam using xcode4 with ios 4.3.And my device version is ios5.So please tell me how to solve this one.This problem will be faced in device only.In simulator it will be working fine.

Comment: Without breakpoints , your application is running or not?

Comment: It's running without breakpoints

Comment: I have read for running ios5 , you should have xcode 4.2 for all the features. This might be the issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the build configuration to 'Debug' mode. Currently you are probably in the 'Release' mode where breakpoints aren't fired.

Comment: No use.Breakpoints were not fired.Please check Iam developing app in xcode 4 with ios 4.3 sdk.And iam running my app in iphone 4 with ios 5 version.

Comment: Once again. Go to the menu: Product > Edit scheme... Select Run [YourAppName] on the left, open the 'Info' tab and make sure that 'Build Configuration' is set to Debug.