# How to run the app in Iphone 4 with iOS5 with breakpoints?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run the iphone app in xcode4 with breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925644/how-to-run-the-iphone-app-in-xcode4-with-breakpoints)

Iam developing one application.At last week i can upgraded my iphone 4 with ios5.And iamdeveloping my applcaion with xcode 3.2.5.And if iam running my applciation in iphone 4 then breakpoints are not fired.SO please tell me how to solve this one.